# Ruby (Rails) における、使用可能なオプションの調査方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

お世話になります。

自分は元Javaソフトの保守をやっていました。
現在、Ruby on Rails を使って、開発に取り組んでおります。

メソッド引数において、ハッシュを用いた可変長的なオプションの指定が、Ruby on Railsの特徴と思っていますが、
オプションで指定できるもの（指定を想定されているもの）の一覧を表示することは可能でしょうか。
リファレンスなどから、読み解くしか無いでしょうか。

調査時間短縮のため、ご教示くださいますと幸いです。

### 補足(経緯)

現状解決している悩みですが、上記の相談に至った経緯はざっくり以下のような感じです。

- 現状動いているDBに、commentを含むカラム追加が必要になった。
- 新たにmigrationファイルを出力した。(rails g migration AddTo~~を使って)
- add_column というメソッドが生成されたが、commentの追加方法がわからない。
- ネット上で検索をしてみたが、先人の知恵が見つからない。
- ソースコードをざっくり見てみたところ、comment を含む定義が見つかった。
- ただ、明確な指定方法がわからなかった。
- 末尾に comment: "***" を単純に追加したところ、migrationで反映された。

Comment: `bin/rails --help` で表示される一覧はご覧になったでしょうか？ [Rails のコマンドラインツール - Rails ガイド](https://railsguides.jp/command_line.html)

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。わかりにくい質問となっており、申し訳ございません。bin/rails --help で表示されるものは、Rails に関するコマンドラインのヘルプのように見受けられます。恐れ入りますが、今回ご質問させていただいたのは、メソッドの引数に関するものです。本文内にあります、add_column メソッドを例にしますと、rails のソースコード上では def add_column(table_name, column_name, type, options = {}) というように定義されており、このoptionsを受け取るということは理解できます。しかしながら、どんなオプションの指定が想定されているのか分からず、明確な調査をしようとすると、呼び出し階層を大きく遡ったりする必要があるように考えられます。新バージョンに伴い、便利なオプションが新しく整備されて、名前からその機能を類推できるような美しいものだったとしても、それを認知できずに車輪の再開発を繰り返すことになりそうに思います。

Answer (score 1):

rails における、 api ドキュメントのオフィシャルっぽいものは、以下のサイトから参照できます。

> https://api.rubyonrails.org/

今回の、 `add_column` については、上から検索していくと、次のページが発見され、そこから、 `comment` オプションの説明についても、参照できたかな、と思っています。

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column